# Vimeo API Delete a video

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm a little bit confused how to delete a video with the new API from Vimeo. I'm succeeded to create an application that uploads with the post function `$vimeo->request()`.

But I have no clue how to delete a video.

The `Vimeo API Docs` are good but I need some example or a hint. I'm developing in PHP right now so if someone could help me it would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete a video, you need the Video URI (It will look something like /videos/12345).

Then you make an authenticated DELETE request against that URI. In the PHP library, it would look like this:

```
$vimeo = new Vimeo(YOUR_APPLICATION_ID, YOUR_APPLICATION_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN);
$vimeo->request($uri, array(), 'DELETE');
```

Comment: Must there be any any data in the array() ?

Comment: The array is a list of querystring, or body parameters (depending on your HTTP method). None of our delete requests require parameters (so it can remain empty!)